# Looking for a JavaScript carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am looking for a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) based carousel such as [absolute website](http://www.absolut.com). The main part that I am interested in is that it slides in a similar way to the main site flash, highlighting one item/image at a time and items are in a line.

Plug-in for any kind of library is welcome but indeed I would prefer [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) based one as I have used it for my earlier works.

And yes I have done lots of googling but wasn't lucky enough :)

Comment: Absolute's one is made in flash. I'd love to see it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery UI Carousel](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel/demo/index.html). It's still in development, but usable :)

Answer (score 3):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) is still a classic.

I can't open your example so I'm not sure it has all the features you want.

Comment: should it worry me that their download zip file is jQuery 1.2.3 ?

Answer (score 1):

[MooFlow](http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/example-ajax.html) is beautiful!

**EDIT**: ImageFlow seems to a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a jQuery user. I've just used [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) w/ jQuery 1.3.2. on a [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) 1.5.x.

It works fine even on Internet Explorer 6 (which is a pretty good thing, hehe). Hope it helps.